# Layout messes up when moved to stylesheet

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am a new one to ASP.NET and currently learning from the book "Beginning ASP.NET with Visual Studio 2015" by William Penberthy. In the chapter 7 about layout with master pages I created a custom master page WebForms with stylesheet RentMyWrox and moved the inline style for various controls of the page ManagedItems.aspx to RentMyWrox.css. This cause the layout to mess up.

When I switched back to default master page and added the inline style to default Site.css stylesheet the layout was displayed correctly. I downloaded the source code for the book and it has the same issue. Could anyone explain, what is the problem?

My custom master page WebForms.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForms.master.cs" 
    Inherits="RentMyWrox.WebForms" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="Content/RentMyWrox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            Navigation content here
        </div>
        <div id="section">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer content here
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet for custom master page RentMyWrox.css

```
body {
    font-family: verdana;
}
#header {
    background-color:#C40D42;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section {
    width:750px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:#C40D42;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}
.dataentry input{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.dataentry textarea{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.dataentry label{
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#fuPicture {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

Page ManagedItems.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/WebForms.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageItem.aspx.cs" Inherits="RentMyWrox.Admin.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name" 
                AssociatedControlID="tbName"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Description" 
                AssociatedControlID="tbDescription"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription" runat="server"
                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Cost" 
                AssociatedControlID="tbCost"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Item Number" AssociatedControlID="tbItemNumber"/>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbItemNumber" /> </div> <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Picture" AssociatedControlID="fuPicture"  />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuPicture" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="dataentry">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Acquired Date" AssociatedControlID="tbAcquiredDate"/>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbAcquiredDate"/>
        </div>
        <asp:Button Text="Save Item" runat="server" OnClick="SaveItem_Click" /> 
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

This is how it should look according to the book
[image: How it should look]

This is how it actually looks like
[image: How it actually looks like]

The source code can be downloaded at http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/27/11190774/DOWNLOAD/RentMyWrox_Chapter7_CSharp..zip

Answer (score 0):

Is the code attached/linked the "before" or "after" modification code?
My recommendation is to use the tools of your browser to check if the CSS file was actually loaded. In Chrome, you can press F12 and then click on the "Sources" tab. This will show you what is loaded down the left, I'm guessing your CSS file is not there.

If that's the case, it might be your reference in your master file.
Currently you have it as:

But that link is not a valid link from your manageitem.aspx page which is inside the 'Admin' folder.

Instead, try "~/Content/RentMyWrox.css" - this should map the proper path from the root of your application, rather than relative to whichever child page is loading the master.